# Click Once Random Install Prompt

Tags: .net, clickonce

I've got a click once application that randomly reshows the install prompt.  It seems like I notice it first thing in the morning, though I can't say that is always when it happens. (Computer left on over night, but screen locked)  Their are two scenarios that open our application, one is directly from the start menu and the other is by way of another application that basically passes the network path to the myapp.application file to iexplore.exe.  I can usually get it to reproduce sometimes if when it happens the first time I then shutdown the application and alternate between the two ways of opening it. This morning I opened via the secondary application, got the install prompt clicked install, then once the application was started, closed it and opened it via the start menu and got the install prompt again.  Subsequent attempts did not produce an install prompt.  A couple days ago I got it 4 or 5 times in a row by alternating back and forth.

I've checked dfsvc.exe thinking that maybe it was getting kicked off as a different user from the other application causing click once to not look in the right paths or registry settings, but it is always under my username in task manager (an idea I got from this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/919676cd-39c4-47dc-aa76-afc3c8159ece/how-to-run-a-click-once-app-in-user-environment?forum=winformssetup).  I also used Procmon to check what folders it was accessing under c:\users\myusername\AppData\Apps\Local\Apps\2.0 and it appears to be always accessing the correct folder where the currently installed version of the application exists.

Another weird thing I am noticing that may or may not be related is that if I push out an update and run it via the start menu I see the status bar where it downloads the update.  If I then exit and run it via the secondary application I again get the status bar where it downloads the update.  If I use the same method twice in a row to open the app, I only get the update the first time.

Comment: Does the secondary application run your click once app under a different identity?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be.  That was one of my initial thoughts, but the secondary app is running under my user in task monitor and so is dfsvc.exe

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I'm working with a client with the exact same issue.

Comment: Not sure.  Made a bunch of changes on how the application is invoke and haven't had any complaints recently.  I haven't see it in test in a long time.  I think it had something to to with 32 bit processes interacting with 64 bit processes, but that is just a gut feeling. Sorry that I can't give you a more concrete answer.