# Click Once Application uninstalls itself/Does not pick up that it is installed when signing out of Windows

Tags: c#, vb.net, installation, clickonce, uninstallation

Not sure if anyone else has run into the issue, but here's how it goes. We have created/published a click once application that gets installed at our client's. We do this by simply placing the needed files on the server and the client then just runs the application and they can start working.

This works quite well as our updates are also distributed the same way. The problem is that when some other clients open the application, it prompts them to install the application when it's already installed on the system. We checked the add/remove programs and the application is still there. I also checked the C:\Users[user]\AppData\local\Apps\2.0\ and the files are still there, the application even runs from in that path file but from the shortcut/installation folder in the start menu it keeps on prompting that you need to install it.

I have uninstalled and recopied the files again. Did the installation and the app works fine again. Once you sign out, and sign back in in about +- 40min the app prompts you to install again. If you install it and sign out and back immediately the app still works and does not prompt to re-install again.

**NOTE**: The client user is not a roaming profile (we checked that first). Also the application is installed and run from the same user. (checked that as well)

The thing that gets me is that it works perfectly fine at other clients but it does this at others.

If anyone has any idea why this might happen or any possible fixes please let me know. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452859/click-once-random-install-prompt) link with a similar issue but no specific fix or explanation. Also could not find any other issues that are the same as what we are experiencing.

Comment: In the publish settings you can choose if the application is available only online, maybe you've set it to that

Comment: Hi @DavidSdot, I quickly checked both apps we use (issue happens too both) and the option: *The application is available offline as well (launchable from Start menu)* is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seemed to solve this problem by using suggestions in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cab966de-034c-4806-b778-f8f2cabaf7d0/clickonce-applications-all-reinstall-after-login?forum=winformssetup) link by:"psl pete" and "TacoGeek".

What we found is that after every sign out/ log off from the user on the computer and re-log in, it would create another registry key entry for HKey_User. Click once then sees it as a new instance and the application is not installed/located in **that** registry, therefore prompting the user to reinstall each time.

When i enabled the following option in the group policy as per the link above:

> *Do not forcefully unload the users registry at user logoff*

This stops creating new "instances" when logging back into the system and the application stays installed. To enable this simply do the following:

1. Open Local Group Policy Editor.
2. In the left pane, open Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > User Profiles
3. In the right pane, double-click on Do not forcefully unload the user
   registry at user logoff.
4. In the resulting window, click in the radio button Enabled.
5. Click OK.

I hope this helps someone else as this has been some headache for us.